# Camera offest when following body

Tags: c#, xna, box2d, farseer

When moving the object around, the camera doesn't remain centered on the object.

I can't seem to locate the bug. Please help.

Initial-

```
`ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(body.Position)-(Camera._screenCenter- Camera._cameraPosition)`
```

This returns zero.

After some movement it changes.
[image: Initial State]

[image: After moving the body]

I am using Farseer Physics Engine 3.5 and moving the body using force.

```
body.ApplyForce();
```

This is my Camera Class-

```
class Camera
    {
        private static Matrix _view;
        public static Vector2 _cameraPosition;
        public static Vector2 _screenCenter;
        private static float _zoom;
        private static float _rotation;

        public static void Load(GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics)
        {
            _view = Matrix.Identity;
            _cameraPosition = Vector2.Zero;
            _screenCenter = new Vector2(_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, _graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f);
            _rotation = 0f;
            _zoom = 1.0f;
        }

        public static void HandleInput(KeyboardState state)
        {
            if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Add) && _zoom < 1.0f)
                _zoom += 0.1f;
            if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Subtract) && _zoom > 0.1f)
                _zoom -= 0.1f;

            Update();
        }

        public static void Update()
        {
            _view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(
                                        new Vector3(_cameraPosition - _screenCenter, 0f)) *
                                         Matrix.CreateRotationZ(_rotation) *
                                         Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(_zoom, _zoom, 1)) *
                                         Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(_screenCenter, 0f));
        }

        public static void Follow(Body body)
        {
            if (body != null)
                _cameraPosition = _screenCenter - ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(body.Position);
        }

        public static Matrix getView()
        {
            return _view;
        }
    }
```

[image: Debug Info]

Answer (score 0):

Your `_screenCenter` is the origin of the camera, and is not being calculated correctly when you make the matrix.

Try:

```
        return Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position, 0.0f)) *
               Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Origin, 0.0f)) *
               Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
               Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom, Zoom, 1) *
               Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Origin, 0.0f));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I modified the update according to your suggestion.
Using the (-)Position, but It didn't solve the problem. The Body moved off Screen.
To fix that I reversed the -ve. But the original bug exists.

Comment: I also changed how the origin was calculated, take a second look. (or am I misunderstanding)

Comment: `_screenCenter = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_cameraPosition, 0.0f)) *
               Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_screenCenter, 0.0f)) *
               Matrix.CreateRotationZ(_rotation) *
               Matrix.CreateScale(_zoom, _zoom, 1) *
               Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(_screenCenter, 0.0f));
`
Is this what you suggest??
In this case screenCenter is a Vector2 and Matrix to vector2 conversion is not working.

Comment: Initially this returns zero-
`ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(_tyre.body.Position)-(Camera._screenCenter- Camera._cameraPosition)`

But after movement it changes.

Comment: B.T.W - Loved Zarknorth. The Design is great. :D

Comment: Sorry I didn't phrase my answer right, you should use that code to define your `_view` in your update method, not for setting the `_screenCenter`. Also, as a young developer who was never taught programming or graphics and somehow picked it up as a hobby, thanks, it means a lot!